# Is UHST RelaySocket used for p2p connection?

Tags: webrtc, p2p

In UHST 2.0 (https://github.com/uhst/uhst-client-js/commit/5888b6d4583c91bd30a04d289e0ff0aa9ce9b5f0) WebRTC is no longer the default transport protocol between peers and instead a new `RelaySocket` has been introduced. What is this RelaySocket and is it still peer-to-peer or depends on a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **no, with RelaySocket the connection is not peer-to-peer**.

In UHST 1.x the relay was used for signalling the WebRTC connection (ICE peer exchange), but once WebRTC DataChannel is successfully established, the clients close the relay connection and all data transport is through WebRTC. The host keeps the relay connection open to signal new peers that need ICE exchange.

UHST 2.0 introduced the concept of RelaySocket which is an implementation of the UHST protocol over the relay instead of over WebRTC. WebRTC is still bundled with the JS client and can be enabled. With RelaySocket the relay acts as a man-in-the-middle which forwards messages between the clients and the host.

The main reason for switching to RelaySocket is to enable interoperability with mobile UHST clients (Flutter, iOS, Android) where WebRTC implementations are not readily available or standard. Also, if porting UHST to IoT devices WebRTC may not be available.